# How is the Parse.com error message "Method requires Pinning Enabled" related to this human error?

Tags: parse-platform

I am using Parse with local datastore enabled. I maintain two backends, one for development, another for testing and comment out one or the other.

After one edit, I got the error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Method requires Pinning enabled.'*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106665c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001062febb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106665b9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   MyAppName                       0x00000001053e5fad -[PFQuery fromPinWithName:] + 65
    4   MyAppName  

//and so on..
```

By back-tracing what I did, I found that I had left both the back-ends enabled by mistake as follows:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //-----------------Parse customizations------------------------------


        // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.
        // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

        // ****************************************************************************
        // Uncomment this line if you want to enable Crash Reporting
        // ParseCrashReporting.enable()
        //
        // Uncomment and fill in with your Parse credentials:

        //This one is for the MyAppName Parse App

        MyModel.registerSubclass()


// This the main App
       Parse.setApplicationId("someId1", clientKey: "someKey1")

//This is the test app
        Parse.setApplicationId("anotherID2", clientKey: "anotherKey2")

//Note: Only one of the above should be enabled, not both
//In this instance, I forgot to uncomment the first resulting in the error message.


//and so on..
```

In this case I found the mistake by means not related to the error message. So what is logical thought process that would have enabled me to go from the error message to my error?